# Extract data underlying Excel pivot tables with many records

Tags: excel

I have an `.xlsx` with a pivot table but not the Access database that it links to. However, I believe all of the "raw" data underlying the pivot table is in the cache somewhere within the spreadsheet. My end goal is to create a CSV with the raw data. The issue with double-clicking the 'totals' row is that I'm limited to 2^20 (~ a million) rows, and the data has around 8 million. I'm currently manually filtering on a specific field `foo` in the pivot table then double-clicking the totals rows for each value of `foo`. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to save data directly from the PivotCache into a CSV. Looks like you'll have to dump the data from Access.